# Правильна ли пунктуация? (2)

Tags: пунктуация

**И вообще затыкать кого-либо, ты — не имеешь права.**

Answer (score 1):

Предложение лучше оформить так:

***И вообще, затыкать кого-либо  // ты не имеешь права.***

***И вообще*** — в данном случае это вводное слово, которое обособляется, после него делается пауза.

**Тире** ставить не нужно, на этом месте в любом случае делается произносительная пауза.